# generating "useful" backtraces in kubuntu

Tags: kde, crash, dolphin

I have recently switched to kubuntu and I love it, all apart from the bugs! In particular I love Dolphin (as much as I loath all the other linux file managers) but sometimes it just quits on me. It used to straight up disappear so I was delighted when, after installing some updates today, it happened again and I got the "Crash Reporting Assistant". Progress I thought. Sadly though I have been unable to report any bugs so far as it won't let me submit a report without a "useful" back trace. The key to this is apparently to have the correct degug symbols installed on my machine. No problem with a Debian based distro one might think but even though I have installed dolphin-dbg (and after some googling kdelibs5-dbg) it is still failing to generate a "useful" trace. Clicking on "list of files" gives me the following message...

"The packages containing debug information for the following application libraries are missing:
* /usr/bin/dolphin
* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5"

So if I haven't installed the right symbols packages what are the right symbols packages? I've had a look through the backtrace as it stands and tried grepping apt-cache for debug packages related to various odds and sods I saw in there but found nothing useful looking.